# Which is the best MongoDB architecture to work with friends or followers list?

Tags: mongodb, performance, mongodb-query

I'm developing a social media and I need to create friend list and followers list, but the followers list I'm thing about performance in queries, then I have in my mind two options but I don't know exactly what is the best:

```
First strategy:
{
 id: "any_id",
 follower_id:"follower_id",
 user_id:"user_id"
}

Second strategy:

{
 id: "user_id",
 user_followers: [ { id:"follower_1" }, {id:"follower_2"} ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first strategy is better ,
for serveral reason
for example ,

if the follower_id and user_id store in another collection
getting the list of followers when it grows up , you could use `skip` , `limit` and pagination, but split list of followers in array needs more process when the list grows up,
update of list of followers in strategy one is more simple and faster than of updating in array